# Store output value in variable and do arithmetic operation in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am doing  powershell script for getting memory value of some process in powershell also i need to divide the value by 1024 in order to convert KB/MB.

For example

> PS >>$memory = Get-Process nginx | Select-Object WS | format-wide -Column 1
>
> PS >>$memory
>
> 62541824

This value is in bytes. I need to convert this value into KB/MB. so I performed div operation after that.

> PS >> $memory = $memory / 1024

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Division'.

> At C:\script\tomcat-mem.ps1:3 char:13
>   + $mem= $mem / <<<<  1024
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Any one help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're piping to `format-wide`, you're returning an object rather than a type that can be trivially cast to an `int`. The following would be more suitable:

```powershell
$memory = Get-Process nginx | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WS
$memory / 1024
```

Proof:

```powershell
$m = get-process explorer | select -expandproperty ws
$m.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType


$m = get-process explorer | select ws | format-wide -Column 1
$m.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

You can see that the first version has been implicitly converted to an `Int32`, therefore it's possible to run a division operation on it.